# Proof of the asymptotic expression for the number of self-converse digraphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, directed-graphs

The following expression was mentioned in the master thesis of Alastair Farrugia
[on Page 199](http://www.alastairfarrugia.net/sc-graph/sc-graph-survey.pdf) of his thesis *Self-complementary graphs and generalisations: a comprehensive reference manual*, M.Sc. Thesis, University of Malta, August 1999. The formula I refer to is the following one:

[Asymptotic expression for the number of self-converse digraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxo0d.jpg)

i.e. 
$$
d^\prime_n \sim \frac{2^{(n^2-n)/2}}{n!}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{n/2}\frac{e^\sqrt{n/2}}{e^{1/8}\sqrt{2}}
$$

Is there any references for the proof of this asymptotic formula?

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference purposes (the references are listed in my thesis), Sridharan's formula was given in
M.R. Sridharan, *Asymptotic formula for the number of self-converse
digraphs*, in Proc. Symposium on Graph Theory (Indian Statist. Inst.,
Calcutta, 1976), MacMillan, India, ISI Lecture Notes 4 (1979) 299–
304. [MR 81c:05044](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=553952).

Robinson announced a different formula, but apparently never published the paper:
R.W. Robinson, *Asymptotic number of self-converse digraphs*, announced.

Enumeration is not one of my strongpoints, and I don't have Sridharan's paper, but maybe the techniques used there can help to get Robinson's formula. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: Might Robinson's announcement have been published as: Robinson R.W. (1978) Asymptotic number of self-converse oriented graphs. In: Holton D.A., Seberry J. (eds) Combinatorial Mathematics. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, vol 686. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg. https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0062540 ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a different paper, about a different class of graphs.

An oriented graph has at most one arc between any pair of vertices
A self-complementary digraph has at most two arcs (one in each direction) between any pair of vertices.
A self-converse digraph can have any number of edges, so now for each n we want a counting polynomial which has as the coefficient of x^k the number of self-converse digraphs on n vertices and k edges.